# Incorrect email or password when trying to create Google Alerts using Python

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-chromedriver, google-alerts

When trying to run this code to create Google Alerts:

*google-alerts create --term "hello world" --delivery 'rss' --frequency 'realtime'*

I keep getting this error:

*google_alerts.InvalidCredentials: Email or password was incorrect.*

I tried many times with multiple emails and am sure that my email and password are correct. I'm using Python 3.7.6 and Chrome 81 if that info helps.

https://github.com/9b/google-alerts

Comment: Where are you running this command?